# Unable to determine Electron version. Please specify an Electron version

Tags: electron

I was trying to create executable file for `electron app` but faced this issue

> Unable to determine Electron version. Please specify an Electron version

Though I have `electron` installed on my machine globally but still it was giving me error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install `electron` as `dev-dependency` to resolve this issue

```
npm install --save-dev electron
```

Resources
https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/issues/617