# Electron Forge stuck "Packaging Application"

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I am attempting to publish an application to a public github repo using `electron-forge publish`. `electron-forge make` works fine and I can run the built application. `electron-forge publish` almost seems to work, but it hangs on the `Packaging Application` step.

The exact command I am running is `electron-forge publish --arch arm64,x64`. I've tried setting the `DEBUG` environment variable to `*`, but nothing useful is output. Here is the last few lines of the command output:

```
⠸ Searching for target release: 1.0.0  electron-forge:publisher:github:info GET /repos/owner/repo/releases?per_page=100 - 200 in 234ms +0ms
✔ Searching for target release: 1.0.0
✔ Uploading Artifacts 2/2 to v1.0.0
⠼ Packaging Application
```

Edit, if I remove the `--arch` param then everything works.

Answer (score 1):

If you using the plugin "electronegativity", try to remove it.

Also, another possible solution:

- [Unable to determine Electron version. Please specify an Electron version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52083994/unable-to-determine-electron-version-please-specify-an-electron-version)

If none of this helps, try to set the env variable `DEBUG=*` and run your command again. Probably, it will show the reason.